# mySQL - how to show all records from the messages table, not just one

Tags: sql, mysqli

this is how I build a messaging system for my website and that is how I would like that all conversations between the two uses is a place in alternate several places,

`fra_id` is the one who sends the message

`til_id` it is the person receiving the message.

What the problem is here and now is that it only shows a message even though there are more messages in the conversation.

```
SELECT 
  fms_bruger.fornavn, 
  fms_bruger.efternavn, 
  fms_opslagpm.id, 
  fms_opslagpm.title, 
  fms_opslagpm.besked 
FROM fms_bruger 
INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? 
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title 
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

How can I do this all the interviews have a place rather than on the page.

EIDT

```
$sql = "SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, 
fms_opslagpm.title, fms_opslagpm.besked 
FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN 
fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? 
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title AND fra_id = ? OR til_id = ? 
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC";

if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $fra_id, $til_id);
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $fra_id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $til_id = $_SESSION["id"];
```

EIDT EIDT

```
SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title, 
fms_opslagpm.besked 
FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm 
ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? 
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title 
AND (fra_id = ? OR til_id = ?) 
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

and i have try its here:

```
SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title, 
fms_opslagpm.besked 
FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm 
ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? and (fra_id = ? OR til_id = ?)
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title  
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

and i have try its here again

```
SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title, 
fms_opslagpm.besked 
FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm 
ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? and (fra_id = ? OR til_id = ?) 
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

Comment: Do the messages have the same title?  You're grouping on that field.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yea ;) they have the same title, which change the message and the recipient and sender

Comment: Mixing AND and OR in a `WHERE` clause without parentheses is asking for trouble.  I recommend you use `WHERE A=1 AND (B=2 OR C=3)`, to be clear about how you want the logic to read.  Unless of course you meant `WHERE (A=1 AND B=2) OR C=3`.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades It does not work as you write, it does not work if I do it by GROUP BY or where etc..

Comment: K.  What results are you getting from each query?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I only get a message back and I get no more calls until the page.

Comment: "A message"?  You mean you get one record where you expect more?  Or you get an error message?  You're not giving me much to go on here.  Have you verified that each table has records meeting your parameters?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yes I'm only a message, but did expect a little more on the side when I need to download from fra_id or til_id then there's nothing appears on the page.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.  Is your query returning *one or more records*?  If so, how many?  What were you expecting?  Is it instead returning *an error message*?  If so, what is that error message?

Comment: I get no errors on the page, right now I have two messages from the use which has been sent to user 1

Comment: You mean you're getting two *records* when you run your query?  Is this not what you're expecting?  What are you expecting?

Comment: I expect it to show all messages between the two users.

Comment: The word "user" does not appear in your query.  We're getting nowhere; I recommend you start your question over again, thinking carefully about what you have, what you're getting, and what you expect to get.  Verify that your underlying tables do have the data, so we can be sure that it really is a matter of fixing the query.  If you want us to have a deeper understanding of the fields, I recommend you explain what `fms_bruger` and `fms_opslagpm` represent.  Watch your spelling, too; you've been using "use" where  I *think* you mean "user".  You're not making it easy to help you.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades i have make its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798626/only-displays-a-message-in-the-conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are selecting only

```
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?
```

So it will only return 1 row where there is an exact match on the `id`. It looks like you where trying to also select the rows that have the same `title` as the row with the `id`

```
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title
```

but even if you returned more than 1 row, this would have collapsed the results into 1 row again.

You need to change your query to get the `title` of the row `WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?`, and using `OR` select all the other rows with the same `title`.

Try -

```
SELECT 
  fms_bruger.fornavn, 
  fms_bruger.efternavn, 
  fms_opslagpm.id, 
  fms_opslagpm.title, 
  fms_opslagpm.besked
FROM fms_bruger 
INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE (
       fms_opslagpm.id = ? 
       OR fms_opslagpm.title = (
                                SELECT fms_opslagpm.title 
                                FROM fms_opslagpm 
                                WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?
                                ) 
       ) 
       AND 
       (
       fms_opslagpm.fra_id = ? 
       OR
       fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? 
       )

ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

See this SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d534/6

You will also need to include 1 more param to your `bind_param`

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $id, $id1, $fra_id, $til_id);
                $id = $_GET["id"];
                $id1 = $_GET["id"];
                $fra_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                $til_id = $_SESSION["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GROUP BY` clause is collapsing records with the same `title`.  Add another field to the `GROUP BY` clause, or discard it - it's not currently being used to feed an aggregation anyway.

Comment: I can not quite see what you think of it as you write, I'm sorry, but I just do GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title on to recipient and sender stand by GROUP BY?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's happening without knowing your RDMS, but the function of `GROUP BY` is to collect all records with the same values and calculations such as counts or sums upon those collections.  If you have two records with the same `title`, and the `GROUP BY` is acting on just this field, then those two records will end up in the same collection, and you'll get just one record for them in your result set.  Except that you have extra fields in your `SELECT` list; in most RDMS, this is invalid syntax.

Comment: okay, I use just throwing fra_id and til_id into the GROUP BY and see if it works.

Comment: try adding something else...  or posting better comments to get the answer you seek.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant What you mean??

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I mean that nothing happens in some manner. the show is still only a message.

Comment: You mean you're still only getting one record?  Did you try either of my suggestions, namely adding fields to your `GROUP BY` to ensure you get each result, or better yet dropping it entirely?  It does not appear that you need a `GROUP BY` in this query.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I add 3 suggestions on how I've tried to make it here on.