# only displays a message in the conversation

Tags: php, mysqli

i have make its here before. [mySQL - how to show all records from the messages table, not just one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796953/mysql-how-to-show-all-records-from-the-messages-table-not-just-one)

Hello

This is how I'm going to build a messaging system which make the user 1 and user 2 has a conversation somewhere.

That itself, I go to the site so come all the conversations appear on the page.

the problem is such that it does only one message from the database. Therefore, I would like it to display all messages from the database.

Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fms_opslagpm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fra_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `til_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `besked` longtext NOT NULL,
  `datotid` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `fms_opslagpm` (`id`, `fra_id`, `til_id`, `title`, `besked`, `datotid`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 'hrerherhe', 'hello world ', '2014-04-01 22:25:29'),
(2, 2, 1, 'hrerherhe', 'hej', '2014-04-01 23:51:49');
```

mysqli/php here.

```
$sql = "
                SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.fra_id, fms_opslagpm.til_id, fms_opslagpm.title, fms_opslagpm.besked 
                FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
                WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ? and fms_opslagpm.fra_id = ? OR fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? 
                GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
                ";
                if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
                    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $fra_id, $til_id);
                    $id = $_GET["id"];
                    $fra_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                    $til_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($fornavn, $efternavn, $id, $fra_id, $til_id, $title, $besked);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="postbox">
                        <td class="beskedinfoBOX">
                            <p>
                                <?php
                                    echo $fornavn . " " . $efternavn;
                                ?>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            //beskeden.
                            echo $besked;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                }
```

[image]

This is how when I write fra_id = 2 and til_id = 1, then shows it is still only the content of the page. So samtidigvæk a message on the page.

fms_opslagpm = fra_id - is he / she who sends the message

fms_opslagpm = til_id - is he / she who receives the message

Comment: You will only get 1 returned row because you have `WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?` (so only 1 row with id will match) AND you have `GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title` (so even if you have multiple rows, they would collapse down to 1). Can you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are selecting only

```
WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?
```

So it will only return 1 row where there is an exact match on the `id`. It looks like you where trying to also select the rows that have the same `title` as the row with the `id`

```
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title
```

but even if you returned more than 1 row, this would have collapsed the results into 1 row again.

You need to change your query to get the `title` of the row `WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?`, and using `OR` select all the other rows with the same `title`.

Try -

```
SELECT 
  fms_bruger.fornavn, 
  fms_bruger.efternavn, 
  fms_opslagpm.id, 
  fms_opslagpm.title, 
  fms_opslagpm.besked
FROM fms_bruger 
INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE (
       fms_opslagpm.id = ? 
       OR fms_opslagpm.title = (
                                SELECT fms_opslagpm.title 
                                FROM fms_opslagpm 
                                WHERE fms_opslagpm.id = ?
                                ) 
       ) 
       AND 
       (
       fms_opslagpm.fra_id = ? 
       OR
       fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? 
       )

ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

See this SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d534/6

You will also need to include 1 more param to your `bind_param`

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $id, $id1, $fra_id, $til_id);
                $id = $_GET["id"];
                $id1 = $_GET["id"];
                $fra_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                $til_id = $_SESSION["id"];
```